# segmentation fault and core dump in string

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

program has crashed and the issue is not reproducible
core trace

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00256122 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::c_str() const () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-69.el6.i686 glibc-2.12-1.80.el6_3.7.i686 libgcc-4.4.6-4.el6.i686
(gdb) #0  0x00256122 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::c_str() const () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5
```

---

```
printf("Ending Session: %s"session_->getSessionName());

class
{
        const char* getSessionName() const  { return name.c_str(); }
    private:
        STLPORT::string name;

}
```

can any one suggest the correct answer please ?

classname *session_;

in constructor session_(0) is initialised

Comment: Somewhere in your program you misused a pointer. The 10 lines of code you posted are not even close to enough to figure out where you went wrong. Use a utility like Valgrind to debug it.

Comment: Show more core - how session_ is initialised?

Comment: my wild guess is that `session_` is `NULL` or unintialized because this error is exactly what happens when the pointer to the class instance is invalid

Comment: I strongly suggest to avoid STLPORT::string

Comment: Not sure c_str() should be returned like this... Try `cname = new char[name.size()+1];
strcpy(cname,name.c_str());
return cname;`

Comment: Should there be a comma in here: snip `ssion: %s"session_->ge` snip?